# User timestamp in Column Z across my domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script. It works but each user in my domain has to individually authorize it for it to work.

As domain admin, I want to deploy it across my domain for this sheet and any copy of this google sheet made.

I tried to deploy it as a Web App, but that still doesn't work.

When I try to test the web app, I get the error:

Script function not found: doGet

```
{
  var now2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "E MMM dd, yyyy @ hh:mm a");

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("Z1").setValue("Sheet Last Modified: " +now2);

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 6 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time2 = new Date();
    var user = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "E MMM dd, yyyy @ hh:mm a");
    time2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "E MMM dd, yyyy");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Z' + row.toString()).setValue(time+" by: "+user);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("Z2").setValue("Row Last Modified");


  };


    };
```

Comment: Related [Mass deploy Google Apps Script powered spreadsheet to limited users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24709549/1595451), [Distribute Google Apps Script and push updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16997274/1595451)

Comment: Another related one: [(How) can I publish a Google Sheet and associated Google Apps Script organization-wide and avoid or suppress authorization prompts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39516693/1595451)

Comment: Thanks so much!
I have already tried to deploy as a web app... and tried distributing the app in other ways like this.

The users still get the authorization prompt. :(

Comment: Script function not found: doGet  is the error I am getting when i deploy as a web app.

I cannot deploy as an Add On because it is not enabled for my domain as it could affect HIPAA compliance.